# Rotation Toggle Not Working

Tags: android

I am trying to make a togglebutton that will endable or disable Auto-Rotation on my android device. I was able to get the setting the setting is on or off. But I can't seem change the setting.

```
public void toggleOrientation(View view)
{
    ToggleButton tgOrientation  = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tgOrientation);
    String orientationOption    = Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION;
    int orientation             = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),orientationOption, 0);
    if(orientation == 1)
    {
        android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),orientationOption,0);
        tgOrientation.setChecked(false);
    }
    else
    {
        android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), orientationOption,1);
        tgOrientation.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me if there is a problem in my code?

My testing device is a Tablet. I am not sure if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the orientation change based on the orientation of the device:
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);`

To let device/user decide the orientation:
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);`

To force device to use orientation sensor:
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);`

Just call on button click event. Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation for full details